How to change the granularity in a 12-month time series chart to display points by month instead of days
I'm trying to create a time series chart for my Google Analytics 4 data in Google Looker Studio. I want to show page views for the last 12 months. But instead of a point for every day, I would like a point for every month.
I am using Date as my Dimension and Views as the Metric.
This is attainable in GA4 in the Engagement > Pages and screens report:
GA4 time series report showing drop down menu to display chart by day, week, or month
Here is what I have so far in Looker Studio:
Looker Studio time series chart showing days
Is there any way to make my chart display this same data but with one point for each month (allowing for an at-a-glance comparison of website traffic month-by-month for the past 12 months)?
I've searched for a solution, and I've looked at all of the options in the Looker Studio chart setup and style menus. I don't see any setting that applies to this issue.

Change the dimension to "year month"!
